# JS - Why array.sort() doesn't return the same result for objects and numbers?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Sorting an array of objects (by a property of type number) doesn't return a sorted result like for an array of numbers.
Why so ?
How to make it sort like for numbers ?

**Demo: Sorting an array of numbers**

```js
const sorted = [0,  5,  2, undefined,  3,  1,  4]
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
console.log(sorted);
```

**Demo: Sorting an array of objects**

```js
const notSorted = [
  {i:0},
  {i:5},
  {i:2},
  {i: undefined},
  {i:3},
  {i:1},
  {i:4},
]
  .sort((a, b) => a.i - b.i)
  .map(a => a.i);
  
console.log(notSorted);
```

I am currently on Chrome 90. Maybe some other browsers or engines don't have this issue. Tell me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-sortcompare):

> - If x and y are both undefined, return +0.
> - If x is undefined, return 1.
> - If y is undefined, return −1.
> - If the argument comparefn is not undefined, then
>
>   - Let v be ToNumber(Call(comparefn, undefined, «x, y»)).
>   - ReturnIfAbrupt(v).
>   - If v is NaN, return +0.
>   - Return v.

That explains why it works in the first case because the sorted values are not enclosed in an object. In the second case the values are not `undefined` (only the properties are) so the native `undefined` handling of `Array.prototype.sort()` doesn't take over, which means the callback is being executed even if `a.i` or `b.i` is `undefined`, and it returns `NaN` (not a number).

As the callback returns `NaN` for every `undefined` property, they are considered equal to every other item. That leads to an erratic behavior, which depends on the actual algorithm of `Array.prototype.sort()` in the JavaScript engine.

Here are the return values of the question example for some browsers:

- IE 11: `[0, 1, 2, 5, undefined, 3, 4]`
- Edge Chromium 90: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, undefined, 4]`
- Firefox 88: `[0, 2, 5, undefined, 1, 3, 4]`

Comment: that is right. by taking another array to get store the actual sorting values (inside sort), no `undefined` shows up.

Answer (score 6):

Your sorting algorithm produces, in some instances, `NaN`, since `undefined - someNum` and `someNum - undefined` both result in `NaN`. This means that your callback is [not consistent](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort), which means that the resulting sort order is implementation-defined.

> A function comparefn is a consistent comparison function for a set of values S if all of the requirements below are met for all values a, b, and c (possibly the same value) in the set S: The notation a <CF b means comparefn(a, b) < 0; a =CF b means comparefn(a, b) = 0 (of either sign); and a >CF b means comparefn(a, b) > 0.

> - Calling comparefn(a, b) always returns the same value v when given a specific pair of values a and b as its two arguments. Furthermore, **Type(v) is Number, and v is not NaN.** Note that this implies that exactly one of a <CF b, a =CF b, and a >CF b will be true for a given pair of a and b.

If you ever return `NaN` from a `.sort` callback, your results can be anything at all: the behavior in such a case is **undefined** by the specification (though certain implementations might produce a result that makes more intuitive sense... or not). So, make sure never to return `NaN`. In this case, explicitly test to see if the `.i` property being iterated over is `undefined`, and substitute a different value for it - maybe Infinity or -Infinity.

```js
const sanitize = val => val === undefined ? Infinity : val;

const notSorted = [
  {i:0},
  {i:5},
  {i:2},
  {i: undefined},
  {i:3},
  {i:1},
  {i:4},
]
  .sort((a, b) => sanitize(a.i) - sanitize(b.i))
  .map(a => a.i);
  
console.log(notSorted);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you got an object with an `undefined` property in that array, on which [your comparison function is not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572). You'll need to ensure that it returns a number, not `NaN`. <s>[Chrome uses different algorithms](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort) for sorting number arrays vs object arrays, and that you got lucky in one case doesn't mean it would always work.</s> It does work as expected with the array of plain numbers, since `.sort()` ignores `undefined` array elements (not attempting to compare them against something else) and always puts them at the end of the array.

You can fix it by doing

```
.sort((a, b) => (a.i ?? -Infinity) - (b.i ?? -Infinity))
```

(or `+Infinity`, depending on whether you want your `undefined` values first or last).

Comment: Isn't the V8 article you linked to saying that they did at last fix that problem of using different algorithms by using only Timsort now?

Comment: @Kaiido Ooops, you're right. I think Guerric has the actual answer. Re-reading the article, the key sentences are "*The basic idea is to collect all non-undefined values into a temporary list, sort this temporary list and then write the sorted values back into the actual array or object.*" and "*the spec requires that `undefined`s must be sorted to the end. Except, `undefined` values are not actually passed to the user-provided comparison function, …*".